# after rotate PNG image with canvas background is black

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

hi I want to rotate my PNG with this code below :

```
async function rotateImage(imageBase64, rotation) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imageBase64;
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            img.onload = () => {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;

                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.6)";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.save();

                ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
                ctx.rotate(rotation * (Math.PI / 180));

                ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

                ctx.restore();
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
            };
        })
```

this is my image before rotate :
[before rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt7Kf.png)
and this is my image after rotate:
[after rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK5Pf.png)
after rotate background corners of image is black how to transparent?
**NOTE:** I use this PNG for marker of google map.
I read this posts :

[Canvas fillStyle none in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598838/canvas-fillstyle-none-in-html5)

[Transparency context.fill style in canvas html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132064/transparency-context-fill-style-in-canvas-html5)

[How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen)

thanks for helping.

Comment: I think this line is the problem `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.6)";`, you are filling the canvas with a gray colour

Comment: if delete this line background is black

Comment: And if you set it to `ctx.fillStyle = "transparent"` or `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0)"`?

Comment: You are converting the image to an JPEG encoded url. JPEG format does not include transparency (alpha channel). Use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` if you want to keep the alpha channel

Comment: @Blindman67 yeeeesss, thank alot,I did not pay attention to this point at all, thank thank